# Get Account Type Picklist

Tags: apex, visualforce

I am trying to get the Picklist values of the Type field in the Account type. When I do this in my Visualforce page:

```
<apex:inputField value="{!acct.Type}"></apex:inputField>
```

The only possible value is Individual, but when I look at the Account object, I see several other possible values. Does anyone know how I can populate a selectList with all the values? This seems like it should be very simple.

Comment: do you have any record type on Account object or do you see those value on Account detail page ?

Comment: ... as picklist value subsets can be defined per record-type.

Comment: Yep, its all about record type

Comment: I'm seeing them if I go into the admin area and look at Account details on any account. And it's only applicable on a specific record type. I just don't know how to get all those possible values to display in the type dropdown box for a new Account.